# QR codes in Lightbox

Tags: geolocation, lightbox, qr-code

I've gotten myself tangled up with QR codes and geolocations.

I have a MySQL table with latitudes and longitudes, and I have a whole batch of QR Code images. Instead of pre-making images, I'd like to generate them on the fly, then display them in Lightbox, with their name and address.

I've gotten to this point (xxx is the MySQL table)

```
<a href=<?php print "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=230x230&chl=".$xxx->latitude->CurrentValue.",".$xxx->longitude->CurrentValue."'";?> rel="lightbox" title=<? Php print "'".$xxx->name->CurrentValue.", ".$xxx->address->CurrentValue."'";?>
```

This generates an image, but if I then scan the image with a phone (say), I get something like "`http://aa.aaaaaa,bb.bbbbb`" as the link to the map. Of course, that doesn't work. I need a more definitive link.

I'm unsure where to go from here. Ideas would be welcome.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've come some of the way.

If I add "geo:" (no quotes) in the line like this:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=230x230&chl=geo:"
```

I get something readable. Now I need to figure how to put a marker in there, and I'm done!

Paul